# Referencing cells in a range

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a large number of parameters that I have grouped into a named range, `MyParameters`, to make it easier to pass to User Defined Functions.

In a User Defined Function I can retrieve a particular parameter using `row` and `column` notion as follows:

```
aParameter = MyParameters(2,2)
```

I now want to do the same outside of VBA (eg for use in a conditional formatting formula or feed into a normal Excel function).

Is this possible?

```
MyParameters(2,2)
```

does not work in a normal Excel cell.

Comment: Is MyParameters a named range?  If so you need to reference it with `[SheetObject].Range("MyParameters")`

Comment: Yes, it is a named range. Will that syntax work outside VBA? Looks VBAesk. Not near computer so can't check until the morning...

Comment: No, I misunderstood the question.  Blame it on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use the `INDEX` formula:

```
=INDEX(MyParameters,2,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Of course!  I don't know why I didn't think of that (mental blank).  This does exactly what I need.  Not sure why the downvote...  
Thanks for this!